# Alternative to iframe to display pages from outside the server?

Tags: iframe, frame, frames

I want to make a game where you have little avatars walking over pages, simply displaying the page and then adding an extra layer with the game. I started to do it with an iframe but the problem is that some pages block it.

Is there an alternative way to display websites in my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the pages using the object tag, instead. 
i.e 
              `<object height="100%" width="100%" type="text/html" data="MyPage.html">
            </object>`